# Espresso Machine coffee amount

Tags: coffee, espresso

I have a [DeLonghi EC-155](http://www.delonghi.com/corporate_en/products/ec-155/) espresso machine. I can operate the machine, but I don't know how many shots I can make with one load of coffee.

- How much ml has a shot to be?
- How many shots I can make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EC-155 comes with two coffee filters and a measuring spoon; the smaller filter one is for one shot of espresso and the second filter is for two shots (see user manual at, e.g., [here](http://www.wholelattelove.com/manuals/delonghi/delonghi%20EC155.pdf)).

Fill the smaller (or larger) filter with one (or two) loosely filled spoons and press lightly using the disc that is attached to the machine.

A single shot is [considered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espresso) to be about 30 mL (1 US fluid ounce) but this is really a matter of taste and personal preferences. For a single shot in a standard size espresso cup, I would suggest starting with filling half a cup and then adjusting the amount of coffee that you pour to accommodate your taste (and need for caffeine...).

Comment: Hmm i see. I suspected the "taste" measurement. I've already gathered some tastes with my cups at home hehe, thank you for the information!

Comment: Got one. Like it well enough. But I haven't used that dinky little filter thingy since the first week I owned it.